# How to create json file having array in Python

Tags: python, json

I want to create a json file like

```
{
"a":["12","34","23",...],
"b":["13","14","45",....],
.
.
.
}
```

key should come from the list:

```
lis = ['a','b',...]
```

and value from the sql query "select id from" + i , where I am iterating through the list through "i". This query simply returns the column id.

Here is the sample code:

```
lis = ['a','b','c']
len_obj = len(lis)

with open("Dataset.json", 'w') as file:
    for i in lis:
        file.write(i)
        obj_query = i + '_query'       
        obj_query = sf.query("select id from " + i) 
        jsondata = json.loads(json.dumps(obj_query['records']))
        length = len(jsondata)
        i = {}
        k = 0

        for j in range(length):
            obj_id = jsondata[j]['Id']
            # print("id " + obj_id)

            if k == 0:
                ids = "\"" + obj_id + "\""
                k = 1
            else:
                ids = ids + ",\"" + obj_id + "\""  

        if count != len_obj - 1: 
            file.write(ids)    
        else:
            file.write(ids)    

        count += 1
    file.write("}")
```

final output should be like:

```
{
"a":["12","23",...],
"b":["234","456",...],
}
```

This is my first blog and 1st program also.
Please guide me through this.

Please forgive the indentation of the program as I am not able to write it here properly.

Comment: what is `objects `?, cant see it there

Comment: Can you post an example of `Dataset.json` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to condense the whole thing down to just this:

```
import json

tables = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
data = {}

for t in tables:
    results = sf.query("select id from %s" % t)["records"]
    data[t] = [r["id"] for r in results]

with open("Dataset.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simply create a dictionary containing the values you are after and then convert it to json using `json.dumps`

```
import json
data = {}
data['a'] = ["12","34","23"]
data['b'] = ["13","14","45"]
json_data = json.dumps(data)
print json_data
```

Comment: You can even do `with open("Dataset.json", 'w') as file: json.dump( data, file )`.

Comment: @Jaco i tried that but it gave me like 
`{"a":["12,23,45..."]} {"b":["23,45,67..."]}{...} 
I ma posting my code in down below.

Answer (score 0):

@Jaco

```
lis = ['a','b','c']

    with open("Dataset.json", 'w') as file:

        for i in lis:

            obj_query = i + '_query'       
            obj_query = sf.query("select id from " + i) 

            jsondata = json.loads(json.dumps(obj_query['records']))
            length = len(jsondata)

            # create dict
            data1 = {}
            k = 0
            for j in range(length):
                obj_id = jsondata[j]['Id']
                # print("id " + obj_id)

                if k == 0:

                    ids =  obj_id 
                    k = 1

                else:

                    ids = ids + "," + obj_id 

                data1[i] = [ids]

                json_data = json.dumps(data1)

        file.write(json_data)
```

the response i got is

```
{"a":["12,23,34.."]}{"b":["23,45,..."]}{...}
```